# Why does re-running a spark job increase the the time taken to run the job?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm running pyspark on EMR notebooks on AWS.

The first time I ran the job, it took 10 seconds and I verified the data was written to S3.

The second time I ran it, the number of tasks increased from 800 to 5000 and took 3 minutes to perform the exact same job.

I have seen this happen numerous times and tried looking for an explanation but have not found one.

I suspected that it was due to caching the dataframe before writing, so I tried
`spark.catalog.clearCache()` and tried restarting the kernel but nothing has worked so far to reduce the time taken back down to 10 seconds.

Any ideas what might be causing the slowdown and increase in tasks?

Comment: When you write to S3, is that an `overwrite` action or is an `append` action?

Comment: It's set to overwrite @ThiagoBaldim

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing data in S3 if you define as `overwrite` how it works is. The first time you don't have anything in the S3 path. So spark is free to write anything very quickly.

When you write for the second time, how spark works is writing a staging path in S3 until it completes. Removes the older files in your path and finally rewrites the data into the final place.

If your writing is `append` this kind of work doesn't happen, spark does not need to check the previous files before writing and there is no staging.

Comment: I tried an append, it doesn't have any effect. It's still around 3 minutes. I wonder if it has anything to do with EMR studio or polluted memory on the executor but unsure how to check. Thanks for the answer though!